# Can Emrakul's Evangel save me from "destroy all creatures"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent played a "destroy all creatures" card. But I have [Emrakul's Evangel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%27s%5d%2b%5bEvangel%5d) on the field. Is there any way that if I use his ability so that some creature will survive?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. If you use that ability in response to their spell, you still lose everything. Here's how it works, assuming nothing else happens:

- They cast [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrath%20of%20God%5d) (or some other card that destroys all creatures). It goes on the stack.
- You respond by activating Emrakul's Evangel's ability, sacrificing some number of creatures. It goes on the stack on top of the spell.
- The top thing on the stack resolves. That's Emrakul's Evangel's ability, so now you get your 3/2 Eldrazi Horror tokens.
- The next thing on the stack resolves. That's the Wrath of God. It destroys all creatures, including the 3/2 tokens you just created.

If you want something to protect you from that kind of situation by giving you replacement creatures, it generally needs to be a triggered ability. For example, [Abzan Ascendancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbzan%20Ascendancy%5d) gives you Spirit tokens when your nontoken creatures die.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use Evangel to end up with any creatures:

1. Do not use Evangel - Evangel and all other creatures die when the destroy effect resolves.
2. Use Evangel - All creatures you sacrifice die and leave 3/2 horrors behind, then all of these tokens die along with all other creatures when the destroy effect resolves.

What you are looking for is to be able to activate the Evangel and have the effect resolve after the desroy effect. The only way that would happen is if the Evangel was activated and in response the destroy effect was put onto the stack, something like [Rout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRout%5d) could cause that.